# Комментарии к посту канала от имени этого же канала / бота

Tags: python, aiogram, бот

В общем, задача:

Есть канал в телеграмм, в него добавлен бот. В канале включены комменты через группу, в группу бот добавлен тоже. Нужно каким-то чудом ботом отставлять комментарии к постам (мол нажимаем на кнопку leave comment и переходим в дискуссию, тут от бота и нужно комменты оставлять).

Как это сделать? Пробовал брать IDшник канала, IDшник поста и делать reply_to на ID поста - получается обычная пересылка сообщений. Если берем ID чата - то просто, опять же, пересылка сообщений, но никак не написание комментария. Я просто не понимаю логики, как дискуссию что-то написать от имени канала или бота.

Код отправки сообщения, если он как-то поможет:

```
class TelegramSender(metaclass=Singleton):
    def __init__(self, bot_token=settings.BOT_TOKEN):
        self._bot = Bot(token=bot_token)

    async def send_message(self, message, chat_id):
        try:
            timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            message = str(message)[:4000]
            message = f"[{timestamp}]\n{message}"
            print(await self._bot.send_message(chat_id, message, reply_to_message_id=7))
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```